# How to get Serial number of Android device programmatically

Tags: android, serial-number

How to find the serial number of the device with Android. I need a serial number that is in About device -> Status -> Serial number

Build.Serial returns to me a different value

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use this upto Android 7.1(SDK 25)

> Build.SERIAL

And this for Android 8(SDK 26+)

> Build.getSerial()

Comment: For me the old call give me the serial on older OS versions. A newer device (S8 running Oreo) gives me **a** serial but not **the** serial. Meaning: I get a serial number but not the same as the serial which is visible to a user in the UI (image in the question). Don't know if this is a obfuscation due to security or a Samsung-specific thing or what. Worth noting though if you need a number that your user can communicate to you in support situations or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/flawyte/efd23dd520fc2320f94ba003b9aabfce) file for get device id. It works on all device before android Pie. If you targeting pie so you can add below code on gist file.

```
if (serialNumber.equals("unknown")){
   try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           serialNumber = Build.getSerial();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("responseData", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

put this code above this line of code

```
// If none of the methods above worked
if (serialNumber.equals("")) {
    serialNumber = null;
}
```

I tried this code on Nokia 6.1 plus and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You can be get the android serial number using this

```
Build.SERIAL
```

Answer (score -6):

Actually,

> Build.SERIAL

works fine on old and new APIs. 
Tested on:
API 16
API 23
API 26
API 28